# Use of locks in Cuda by Example dot product

Tags: c++, cuda

I am reading through the book ["Cuda by Example" by Jason Sanders and Edward Kandrot](http://www.physics.drexel.edu/~valliere/PHYS405/GPU_Story/CUDA_by_Example_Addison_Wesley_Jul_2010.pdf) and have a question about their use of locks for computing the dot product of two arrays (found on pages 254-258 of link pdf). They define their lock.h header file:

```
#ifndef __LOCK_H__
#define __LOCK_H__


struct Lock{
    int *mutex;
    Lock(){
        int state = 0;
        cudaMalloc((void**)&mutex, sizeof(int));
        cudaMemcpy(mutex, &state, sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    }

    ~Lock(){
        cudaFree(mutex);
    }

    __device__ void lock(){
        while (atomicCAS(mutex, 0 ,1) != 0);
    }

    __device__ void unlock(){
        atomicExch(mutex, 0);
    }
};


#endif
```

They then call their dot product kernel like:

```
int main()
{
    // bunch of code, initialization etc

    Lock lock;
    dot<<<blocksPerGrid,threadsPerBlock>>>(lock, dev_a, dev_b, dev_c);

    // more code, frees, etc
}
```

The dot kernel is declared as:

```
__global__ void dot(Lock lock, float *a, float *b, float *c);
```

Doesnt this create an invalid free because the Lock struct contains no copy constructor? We pass the lock by value which simply copies the mutex pointer by value. When we exit the kernel the destructor calls cudaFree on this mutex pointer. When we then exit the main function the destructor is then called again I think but now mutex has already been freed! I ask because in a different larger code I get cudeErrorInvalidDevicePointer errors when using this same idea and I think the problem is that there is no copy constructor.

Comment: Sure but my question is whether the lack of a copy constructor is the problem. Remember this code is not mine. It is an example from the published book linked and I am basically asking if they made an error by not including the copy constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you're right, an extra dtor call will be made - as you could also check for yourself...

Here's a simple example to verify:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>

struct A {
    A()  { std::cout << "ctor for " << this << std::endl << std::flush; }
    ~A() { std::cout << "dtor for " << this << std::endl << std::flush; }
};

__global__ void foo(A device_a) { }

int main(void) {
    A host_a;
    foo<<<1,1>>>(host_a);
    cudaDeviceReset();
    return 0;
}
```

the output is:

```
ctor for 0x7ffe584c85bf
dtor for 0x7ffe584c85df
dtor for 0x7ffe584c85bf
```

So, you're getting the default copy ctor; and the construction and destruction of both copies **happen on the host** (those are host-only functions and the device doesn't have `<iostream>`). I actually find that a bit strange, but I suppose this is part of CUDA's "C-ish" origins, treating kernel parameters like POD. It's particularly surprising seeing how ctors and dtors can have `__device__` and `__host__` qualifiers.

However, the extra call to `cudaFree()` in that example should not be a problem (fingers crossed): The CUDA Runtime API manual, section 3.9 says the call is supposed to fail and return `cudaErrorInvalidDevicePointer`.

Still, that's poor programming practice and the struct should be written differently IMO.

Comment: Ok thank you. It is as I suspected but I just didn't think I would be right over a book and second guessed myself.